# Jetpack Compose TextToolbar not showing for TextField in ModalBottomSheet

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

In Jetpack Compose I have a `TextField` in a `Surface` and it displays the `TextToolbar` (just for a `Paste`) without issues. If I put the same `TextField` into a (`material3`) `ModalBottomSheet` I do not see that toolbar? How can I show the toolbar for a ModalBottomSheet? What is causing the toolbar to stay hidden?

I've created a [minimal demo here](https://github.com/purposebakery/TextToolbarInBottomSheetDemo) for others to reproduce the issue. All the important stuff is in the [MainActivity here](https://github.com/purposebakery/TextToolbarInBottomSheetDemo/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/purposebakery/texttoolbarinbottomsheetdemo/MainActivity.kt).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you mixing Material Composables with Material3 Composables? Please provide the code that you currently use, including the imports.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I've now provided a proper demo to replicate the issue. All important components are material3: https://github.com/purposebakery/TextToolbarInBottomSheetDemo/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/purposebakery/texttoolbarinbottomsheetdemo/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Also, if you want to stay updated about that manner, there is an issue for this in the Google Issue Tracker: that includes the explanation why it does not work: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/307329984

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack Compose is still a relatively new framework, and as such, some features are not supported yet. As far as I know, **the TextToolbar is not supported to be used inside a ModalBottomSheet**([Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/307329984)). This is because the ModalBottomSheet takes up the entire screen, and the TextToolbar is not positioned correctly in this context.
If you need a toolbar for your bottom sheet, I think you have two options :
**1.** Use a trailing `Past` icon with textField(easy way that works fine)
**2.** Create a **custom toolbar component** that is specifically designed to be used in ModalBottomSheet
Implementing the *second way* could be a little complex. I tried to implement this method in general. 
This is a summary of what my code does:
**1.** I made a new composable **specifically** for using inside modal (*TextFieldWithCustomToolBar*)
**2.** The new composable has a `TextFild` and a `DropdownMenu` which will act instead of native toolbar
**3.** We need to detect long press on `TextFild`,
Jetpack Compose has modifiers for handling various gestures, including drag, click, and scroll, but it doesn't work directly on text fields. This is because text fields have their own built-in gesture-handling system that intercepts user interactions before they reach the pointer input modifier. So I did it manually by collecting information from `interactionSource`

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldWithCustomToolBar(
    supportingText: String,
    onPasteRequested: () -> Unit
) {

    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val viewConfiguration = LocalViewConfiguration.current

    //wait for a long press action
    LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
        var isDown = false
        interactionSource.interactions.collect { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                    isDown = true
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        delay(viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis)
                        if (isDown) expanded = true
                    }
                }

                is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                    isDown = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Box {
        TextField(
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            value = text.value,
            onValueChange = { text.value = it },
            supportingText = { Text(text = supportingText) }
        )

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem({ Text(text = "Paste") }, onClick = {
                expanded = false
                onPasteRequested.invoke()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

If the popup padding is a problem for you, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74441726/7756492)

Comment: I was worried I'd get that "is not supported" in an answer... Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue for this on the Google Issue Tracker, you might want to reference it in your answer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/307329984